# Библиотека символьных вычислений для Java (like Sympy)

Tags: java, математика, библиотеки

Хочу написать небольшую программку на Java для упрощения полиномов, нужна для регрессионного анализа данных эксперимента.

Вот такой линейный полином:

```
y = b0 + x1*b1 + x2*b2 + x3*b3 + x1*x2*b12 + x1*x3*b13 + x2*x3*b23 + b123*x1*x2*x3
x1 = (f1-c1_0)/deltaf1
x2 = (f2-c2_0)/deltaf2
x3 = (f3-c3_0)/deltaf3
c1_0-c3_0, deltaf_1-f_3, bi = const
```

Но мне кроме вычисления его значений каждый раз нужно получать уравнение в символьном виде с подставленными в него коэффициентами. Причем количество переменных может изменяться, поэтому не хочется для каждого случая вручную раскрывать скобки. Тем более, что в планах осилить работу с полиномами 2ой степени.

Сейчас большую часть считаю в Excel, а упрощаю полином в Maxima. Попробовал упрощать полином в Python + Sympy - разобрался всего за 15 мин. Но поскольку сейчас учу Java решил писать на ней, а не на Python. 
Знаю, что есть Jython, но это уже какой то велосипед получится. Все найденные мной варианты библиотек, например dmelt монстроподобны для моих нужд.

Буду благодарен даже за подсказку просто ключевых слов для поиска.

Искал по ключевым словам: java symbolic expression expand

### UPD

потратил пару вечеров на попытку найти, то что нужно, вот результаты моих изысканий:
**Symja** - Java Computer Algebra Library. 
https://bitbucket.org/axelclk/symja_android_library/wiki/Home
Symja - Java computer algebra and symbolic math library. Differentiation, integration, equation solving, polynomial factorization and linear algebra functions.
зеркало на github почему то уже называется symja android library
https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library

Подключал самый свежий jar, в IntelliJ IDEA добавил как библиотеку, использовал примеры, взятые из битбукета. Не один не завелся, все валиятся с java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

**jscience**

To provide the most comprehensive JavaTM library for the scientific community.
To create synergy between all sciences (e.g. math, physics, sociology, biology, astronomy, economics, etc.) by integrating them into a single architecture.
To provide the best on-line services (webstart) for scientific calculations and visualizations
(ссылку система не дает вставить)

Для себя не нашел ничего полезного, работает с комплексными числами, но это далеко от того, что мне нужно.

**jscl-meditor** - java symbolic computing library and mathematical editor

Интерактивное приложение, нет никакой документации по API и использованию в качестве подключаемой библиотеки.

**Jasymca** is an interactive System for solving math problems.
Интерактивное приложение, нет никакой документации по API и использованию в качестве подключаемой библиотеки.

**Jep Java** parses and evaluates mathematical expressions with only a few lines of code. This package allows your users to enter a formula as a string, and instantly evaluate it. 
Интерактивное приложение, нет никакой документации по API и использованию в качестве подключаемой библиотеки + Trial License

на тостере подсказали **SymJava**
Документации нет, только несколько примеров не подходящих под мою задачу в \SymJava-master\bin\symjava\examples

**JlinAlg** о нужном мне функционале не заявлено.

**Orbital CAS** из-за названия неосилил нагуглить, - тонны мусора, прямо как на орбите ;)